Quantum computing using trapped ions
I have been trying to understand the basic ideas behind using trapped ions for quantum computing. I've gone through multiple books and articles, but they all assume a QM/Higher Mathematics background. I have neither, so they very quickly become very difficult for me to understand.
Can somebody please answer the following questions at a high level, with as little QM and Higher Maths background as possible so the answers are accessible to people like me? I'm asking these questions for optical qubits.

I understand that for trapped ions, we use two energy states of the ion - ground and excited - to represent $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. We use laser pulses to interchange them, and they do so through either absorption or emission of photons. Is this understanding correct?

How is Hadamard gate physically implemented here? AFAIK, energy states are discrete so you're either in one or the other. So what physical operation puts an ion in an in-between energy state?

What physical characteristic of the ion is used to indicate negative amplitued of $|1\rangle$ (as in when we apply H on $|1\rangle$, we get $1/\sqrt{2}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)$)?

How is Z gate physically implemented? Does it use the same physical characteristic I've referred to in #3 above, to represent negative amplitued of $|1\rangle$?


Thanks in advance.

Not sure any of this can be answered without quantum mechanics, that's the whole point. Eg you need the concepts of superposition, unitary evolution...
